# Change Initiation Parameters for SharePoint 2007 Workflow

Tags: 2007, designer-workflow

I created a workflow in SPD that initiates when a new item is added to a list.  Unfortunately, the workflow is also initiated when an existing item is updated (a list field titled "Status", when changed to "Closed" intending to close the record from further editing and filtering from "Active Items" list).

I envisioned the workflow sending an email to a manager for approval on the list record when it is created.  That works, but it also sends the same email when the list item status field is changed from "In Process" to "Closed".  This annoys and confuses the managers and I'm not sure how to go about changing this activity.

Please advise, where can I change the initiation parameters on an existing list created in SPD2007?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the initiation parameters when a workflow is started automatically. But If you want to stop the workflow from starting when an Item is changed:

1. Double click the workflow in SPD to edit it
2. Click "< Back" from the first step
3. Deselect "Automatically start this workflow whenever an item is changed"

But for your workflow you also have to option of adding a condition checking the value of "Status" before sending the mail.

FYI. Initiation parameters are values the user can enter when they are starting the workflow manually.

Answer (score 1):

[image]In SPD in the Ribbon you can use Initiation parameters and Variables. These will allow you to use them across the whole life-cycle as well as generating automatic fields on your forms (Initiation form - when workflow is triggered, o Association - when Administrator associates the WF with your list or content type).